# Spring Security CORS with Angular 16

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

First of all my setup. I am using Spring-boot 3.1 with spring security. The api is the spring boot application while Angular is the client application both running on different hosts. Spring boot runs on host http://api.example.com while angular runs on http://client.example.com.

This is my configuration for CORS at the moment.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://client.example.com"));
    
        // tried this too but without any luck.
        // configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("localhost:4200"));

        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

AS from the spring documentation CORS has to be configured first.

I have two kinds of requests one that fetches resources from the database(this one passes cors with the above configuration). And one that uses WebClient to make a request to keycloak to perform the login operation(this one is failing due to CORS).

By now i understand or i think i understand that WebFlux uses Webclient. That means that i have to configure security for webflux???

And this is where i am loosing it. I tried the bellow configuration but without any luck.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://client.example.com")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
        .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

console error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.example.com/login' from origin 'http://client.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you setup a Proxy for API Calls ? Are the API working on postman ?

Comment: Yes both apis are working from postman. I have an nginx in front of both hosts.

Comment: Can you try to setup a proxy firstly and try locally the Angular project? In general should work if backend and nginx there is ok. Otherwise something on nginx configs its not allowing the communication. It might be firewall, a closed port ect

Comment: I had a time issue with closed port on server. And teh only way was to contact them with mail in order to open.

Comment: You should consider using spring-cloud-gateway in front of resource servers and Angular host. That way request would have same origin (the gateway) and more importantly, you could implement the BFF pattern (your Angular app should not be an OAuth2 client). Sample there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally manage to get through this.

My first assumption that it was a problem coming from the internal request to keycloak was wrong. I understood that when i created another dummy post request. I had the same issue.

Digging through tons of answers on the web and reading again and again the documentation there was one option i did not follow. The CorsFilter.

After implementing the CorsFilter thought i had the same issue....then just by pure luck i found an issue with my nginx configuration. When i fixed that CorsFilter work like a charm form me. So this is the full implementation hope that will help someone in the future.

One more time my set up:

Spring-boot 3.1 with spring-security enabled this is all that maters at the time.

*SecurityConfig.java*

```
// other security configuration

....    

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

*CorsFilter.java*

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

public CorsFilter() {
    log.info("CorsFilter Init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.your-domain.me");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        return;
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

@Override
public void destroy() {}
}
```

This is the configuration that worked for me. Enjoy!